# Maven installation issue on mac

Tags: java, maven

I have an issue with a Mac.

When running:

```
mvn -v
```

Get the following:

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
> this environment variable is needed to run this program

What I have :

> echo $JAVA_HOME
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home

> echo $M2_HOME
> /Users/username/Downloads/apache-maven-3.9.5

`settings.xml` looks good
`.profile` seems good (using Z sh so updated the `~/.zprofile` too)

Java version 14.0.1.
Mac OS Sonoma 14.0.

I checked Java is installed properly

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to install maven is by command

```
brew install maven
```

which by default as of today install stable 3.9.5 version.

I tried manually installing,
where i faced similar issue when i updated only the

```
~/.zshenv
```

file. So as a comment given above i added the path to my maven at

```
/opt/apache-maven/bin
```

into the ~/.zshrc

```
export PATH={other paths}:/opt/apache-maven/bin
```

Then run

```
exec zsh
```

Close the existing terminal and try in a new one.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the following to check that Java is installed correctly:

> java -version

Output should be something like:

```
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

If your result is different you have not installed Java correctly.
Thus, you need to do it in the correct way.
You could use this tutorial for it: [How to Install Java on MacOS?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-java-on-macos).

Or you could have a look at [SdkMan](https://sdkman.io). It is designed to install tools like Java and Maven.

Comment: I get the same results as shown above when checking for java version, sorry did not mention in the question initially(updated now)

Comment: @MishraS could you share what is the result of execution `java -version`?

Comment: openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update the PATH. In macOS, update your zsh shell configuration file at `~/.zshrc`, for example:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME="${HOME}/DevTools/jdk-17.0.3.7/Contents/Home"
export MAVEN_HOME="${HOME}/DevTools/apache-maven-3.8.6"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thank you. I added to the ~/.zshrc file now. After that I am still getting the same error

Comment: The `MAVEN_HOME` is not needed... only the entry in `PATH` is required... Also I can recommend to use sdkman .... also on Mac...